Unable to dynamically create datasource SpringBoot - 3.3.0
I am trying to develop a spring boot REST application that exposes a Rest endpoints for adding a datasource dynamically without redeployment.
Basically I want to start the application with a primary datasource tenant1 with a person table then after deployment I want to add another datasource tenant2 dynamically which also contains the person table.
I have created 1 default database as follows:
 Tenant 1:  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/primarydb

The configuration for application.yml is as follows:
spring:
  application:
    name: dynamic-demo-db
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false

The following class is used to load the properties:
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dynamic")
public class DynamicDataSourceProperties {

    private Map<String, DataSourceProperties> datasources;

    public Map<String, DataSourceProperties> getDatasources() {
        return datasources;
    }

    public void setDatasources(Map<String, DataSourceProperties> datasources) {
        this.datasources = datasources;
    }

}

Based on the online resources it looks like AbstractRoutingDataSource should be used to implement dynamic datasource as follows :
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

public class DynamicRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
    }
}

The TenantContext is shown below:
public class TenantContext {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> CONTEXT = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setCurrentTenant(String tenantId) {
        CONTEXT.set(tenantId);
    }

    public static String getCurrentTenant() {
        return CONTEXT.get();
    }

    public static void clear() {
        CONTEXT.remove();
    }
}

The configuration of the datasource and transaction manager is defined below:
@Configuration
public class DynamicDataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DynamicDataSourceProperties properties;

    private Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DynamicRoutingDataSource dynamicRoutingDataSource = new DynamicRoutingDataSource();

        properties.getDatasources().forEach((key, dataSourceProperties) -> {
            HikariDataSource dataSource = createDataSource(dataSourceProperties);
            dataSourceMap.put(key, dataSource);
        });

        dynamicRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
        dynamicRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSourceMap.values().iterator().next());
        return dynamicRoutingDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    public void addDataSource(String key, DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = createDataSource(dataSourceProperties);
        dataSourceMap.put(key, dataSource);
        ((DynamicRoutingDataSource) dataSource()).setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);


        ((DynamicRoutingDataSource) dataSource()).afterPropertiesSet(); // Refresh the DataSource routing
    }

    private HikariDataSource createDataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(properties.getDriverClassName());
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(properties.getUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(properties.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(properties.getPassword());
        return dataSource;
    }
}

The methods to add datasource and save a person are shown below:
@Service
public class DataSourceService {

    @Autowired
    private DynamicDataSourceConfig dynamicDataSourceConfig;
    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    public void addDataSource(String key, DataSourceProperties properties) {
        dynamicDataSourceConfig.addDataSource(key, properties);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Person savePerson(PersonRequest personRequest) {
        return  personRepository.save(personRequest.getPerson());
    }
}

Update : Based on the feedback I have added a new header as shown below:

Update : I have also added a new filter class to add tenant in the context before the transaction starts as shown below:
  @Component
    public class RequestFilter implements Filter {
    
        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
            Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void destroy() {
    
            DataSourceContextHolder.clearDataSourceKey();
            Filter.super.destroy();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    
    
    
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
            Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpRequest.getHeaderNames();
    
            String tenant = httpRequest.getHeader("datasource");
    
            if (tenant !=null) {
                TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(tenant);
                DataSourceContextHolder.setDataSourceKey(tenant);
            }
    
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    
        }
    }

The Rest endpoint is shown as follows:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/datasource")
public class DataSourceController {

    @Autowired
    private DataSourceService dataSourceService;



    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public void addDataSource(@RequestParam String key,
                              @RequestParam String url,
                              @RequestParam String username,
                              @RequestParam String password,
                              @RequestParam String driverClassName) throws SQLException {
        DataSourceProperties properties = new DataSourceProperties();
        properties.setUrl(url);
        properties.setUsername(username);
        properties.setPassword(password);
        properties.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSourceService.addDataSource(key, properties);

        dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    @PostMapping("/addPerson")
    public Person savePerson(@RequestBody PersonRequest personRequest) {
        return dataSourceService.savePerson(personRequest);
    }
}
} 

The following screenshot shows payload  to add a datasource:

The above datasource is added successfully and  addPerson result on the newly created database is shown below:

However the record is inserted in tenant1(primarydb) instead of tenant2(secondarydb).
It looks like even if I have added tenant2 with a new database it is not being taken into account.
Records is being saved in the default datasource which is tenant1.
Note: When the jpa:open-in-view: true then it is saved in the primarydb and when it is false no data is saved at all.
Please advice what I am doing wrong?

You are setting the value to the context to late. @Transactional already opens a connection to the databae, and you are setting the value to use for selection after that. Hence it will never go to another database. Next to that this is dangerous as well as you aren't clearing this after the request finished processing.

Thanks Noted @M.Deinum, Any online resource how to add transactional programmatically after setting the value to the context?

You would need to set it earlier, in a Servlet Filter for instance and make sure you disable spring.jpa.open-in-view else it will get a connection very early on.

Maybe I missed it, but I don't see where you call your setCurrentTenant method. Maybe try calling it after your dataSourceService.addDataSource(key, properties);

@M.Deinum I have updated my answer with a filter, I might be missing something since still same behavior as before and when open-in-view: false no data is saved.

@Bakou I have tried it, unfortunately same behaviour

If you are using Hibernate as the ORM I actually implemented this and it's a bit more complicated than what you have here, but to give you a starting point (if you use Hibernate) check: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider

If you are using Spring Data JPA (as your tags state) you are using the wrong transaction manager. You must use the JpaTransactionManager not the DataSourceTransactionManager.
